# How can I get this code to just get the files from an Azure file share?

Tags: c#, azure-storage

My code below needs to get a List from my Azure file share.

I can see from the properties of the share that I have 17 files in 5 folders, however this code returns 29.

*Sample code shown here, not sure how much extra text this editor wants me to add in before it will let me post.*

```
 class Program
    {
        private static List<CloudFile> files = new List<CloudFile>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int xxx = 0;
        string accountName = "#######";
        string key = "#######";
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, key), true);
        var share = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient().GetShareReference("xfer");
        IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = share.GetRootDirectoryReference().ListFilesAndDirectories();



        foreach (IListFileItem listItem in fileList)
        {
            if (listItem.GetType() == typeof(CloudFile))
            {
                files.Add((CloudFile)listItem);
            }
            else if (listItem.GetType() == typeof(CloudFileDirectory))
            {
               files.AddRange(list_subdir(listItem));
            }
        }

    }

    public static List<CloudFile>  list_subdir(IListFileItem list)
    {
        CloudFileDirectory fileDirectory = (CloudFileDirectory)list;
        IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = fileDirectory.ListFilesAndDirectories();

        foreach (IListFileItem listItem in fileList)
        {
            if (listItem.GetType() == typeof(CloudFileDirectory))
            {
                list_subdir(listItem);
            }
            else
            {
                if (listItem.GetType() == typeof(CloudFile))
                {
                    files.Add((CloudFile) listItem);
                }
            }
        }
        return files;
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Dave, if you're running your code in Linqpad5, please include this information in your question. Thanks.

Comment: The answer below is correct, in the Main() method -> else if sentence, you can just use **list_subdir(listItem)**, it works fine in the linqpad5 and vs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies with `files.AddRange`. Here's what's happening:
Say your root directory has two files, A and B, and a folder Foo. Foo in turn contains files C, D and E.

Your code finds Foo and calls `list_subdir`. At this point `files` is still empty. Your loop inside `list_subdir` finds C, D and E and adds it to `files`. At this point `files` contains C, D and E. Now `list_subdir` returns `files` to your loop inside `Main`, where the `AddRange` adds the return value to `files`.

Now `files` contains C, D, E, C, D and E.

The loop continues and adds A and B, making the content of `files` C, D, E, C, D, E, A, B

Et voila. 8 files instead of the expected 5.

If you lose `files.AddRange` you should be good.

By the way, Visual Studio allows you to attach your local debugger to an app on Azure, which makes debugging server-side code like this a doddle.